# ORA-04098: trigger 'triggername' is invalid and failed re-validation

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Hi I have created a trigger as you can see bellow below, but it is giving the following error:

```
ORA-04098: trigger 'APPS.EMP_delete' is invalid and failed re-validation
```

My Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER emp_delete
AFTER DELETE
   ON EMP
   FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

INSERT INTO history_emp   (EMPLOYEE_ID, SALARY, JOB_ID, HIRE_DATE, DEPARTMENT_ID, FIRST_NAME,     last_name, DELETED_BY, DELETION_DATE)
   VALUES
   (:OLD.EMPLOYEE_ID,
     :OLD.SALARY,
     :OLD.JOB_ID,
     :OLD.HIRE_DATE,
     :OLD.DEPARTMENT_ID,
     :OLD.FIRST_NAME,
     :OLD.LAST_NAME,
        USER,
    SYSDATE);

    DELETE FROM BACKUP_EMP WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = :OLD.EMPLOYEE_ID;

END;
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: What error do you get when you create the trigger?  Or when you query `user_errors`?

Comment: Execute the following and paste the results in your question b editing. `SELECT *
 FROM user_errors
WHERE type = 'TRIGGER' AND name = 'EMP_DELETE';`

Answer (score 0):

This means you have some error in the 'APPS.EMP_delete' trigger and it cannot be revalited automaticly. You need to check if your trigger body don't have anything wrong.
Ex.: is the name of all columns from history_emp correct?